# Reason for existence of sort_heap

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

While browsing the less known parts of the standard library, I stumbled onto `std::sort_heap`.
But I don't understand why does it exist since there is a free function named `std::sort`.

Also please note that complexities are the same.

So, my question is: what is the rationale for the existence of `sort_heap`?

Answer (score 13):

`sort_heap` assumes the input to be already in the form of a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29). This means it can theoretically work more efficiently than `std::sort`, since there are some constraints on the order of the input (unlike the `std::sort`, which has to work for all inputs).

As mentioned in the comments it is worth noting that those performance benefits are in no way ensured and obviously depend on the input data, so if performance matters there is really no way around profiling.

Comment: That's not necessarily true - heap sort can have a worse performance than quick/merge sort because of bad cache locality.

Comment: @Ivan You’re ignoring that `std::sort` works on arbitrary array data whereas `std::sort_heap` works on a heap only.

Comment: @Konrad I'm not, really. I just did some tests, and while I don't claim they're perfect, std::sort is consistently faster (not much faster) than std::sort_heap. Also, check out this paper: http://www.lamarca.org/anthony/pubs/cachesort.pdf, pages 19-21 show just performance graphs - although it's for the whole 'build the heap first and then sort', it's usually more than two times slower than quick sort or merge sort. The paper may be a little outdated, but it's the best source I've found on the topic.

Comment: @Ivan Nice research indeed. Kudos.

Comment: @IvanVergiliev: Nice data indeed, I will have to give it a closer reading when I have the time. However from a cursory reading it seems that it only uses 64bit int keys, which is a much better scenario for cache coherent algorithms then sorting e.g. `strings`, so I wouldn't exactly take it as gospel. Still I edited my post to mention that there arent't actual guarantees that `sort_heap` will outperform `sort` (in terms of execution speed).

Comment: @Grizzly definitely, although I wouldn't sort strings using a `sort` function if I was looking for performance anyway :) (Btw I tested some 10^6 random strings of length <=100, and I'm not sure why, but heap_sort is even slower.)

Comment: @IvanVergiliev your link is dead

Answer (score 4):

In the case where the data already has the heap property, there's an obvious sorting algorithm that doesn't apply to data without the property -- repeatedly remove the maximum element of the heap and restore the heap property. This is how heapsort works (first heapify the data, then use the heap property to sort it).

So, suppose that you have a heap and you want it sorted. You could call `std::sort`, but `std::sort_heap` exists to hint that this algorithm be used[*]. It makes at least some sense to provide the programmer with a means to *potentially* improve the sort performance. Whether it's actually faster or not is another matter.

Observe that `std:sort` is permitted to be implemented as a heapsort, although I doubt that it ever is.

The world would go on if `sort_heap` were not available, since there's another way to get the same behavior: repeatedly call `pop_heap` on a smaller and smaller initial segment of your original heap. So if it troubles you, view it as a pure convenience function. It's possible there are optimizations than can be applied, though, to make `sort_heap` a little better than this.

A historical note that might have affected the thinking of the authors of C++03: in the SGI version of the STL, `sort` was defined to use introsort and `partial_sort` was defined to use heapsort. I don't think that's exactly the rationale for including it in the standard, though: it's also an "obvious" function to include with the heap algorithms.

[*] it's a pretty strong hint, since the complexity requirement for `sort_heap` is "at most N log N comparisons", not "O(N log N) comparisons". So an implementation can't have `sort_heap` call `sort` unless it knows that its own `sort` implementation performs at most that many comparisons when the input data has the heap property.

Answer (score 4):

The complexity guarantees are not actually the same.

std::sort requires O(log N) amount of memory on the stack. std::sort_heap requires O(1) amount of stack.
This makes a big difference in an environment where stack space is constrained, for example in embedded applications (i.e., running on a microcontroller). Calling std::sort even on a few thousand element array can cause a stack overflow.

Incidentally, in embedded environments the internal storage is typically SRAM so you don't have to worry about cache locality where quicksort/introsort gain their performance advantage.

Therefore in a microcontroller environment it is advisable to write

```
std::make_heap(data.begin(), data.end());
std::sort_heap(data.begin(), data.end());
```

instead of

```
std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
```

Comment: I would also recommend this in an environment where code size is an issue. Each type you sort (in combination with each different compare function) gives you a distinct and complete sort implementation. This is true for `std::sort` and  for the heap functions; but the two heap functions together generate a lot less code than `std::sort` on the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Code size is a good reason to use the heap sort. These are template functions; for each combination of type being sorted and compare function, you get a  full-blown sort implementation from `std::sort` (i.e. no part of the code for sorting one case is shared with the code for sorting a different case - even if it's the same type, but different compare).

The same is true for the heap sort (i.e. `std::make_heap` followed by `std::sort_heap`) - but the amount of code generated can be considerably less, especially if the compare operator isn't completely trivial; I just did some tests, I was seeing 2k-3k bytes for a `std::sort` and 600-1000 bytes for heap sort of the same operation, on x86.

So if you tend to use a lot of sort operations on different types, and/or with different compare functions, it can be a good idea to use the heap sort for those which tend to operate on smaller N; for these the difference in algorithm efficiency won't hurt it much, and overall code bloat will be reduced.

I suspect that the heap implementation will tend to do more 'swaps' on a given problem, compared to `std::sort`, so if you are sorting a type which is more expensive to swap, it could be noticeably slower - for those cases maybe it's possible to sort an array of pointers instead.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/sort_heap.html

> sort_heap turns a heap [1] [first, last) into a sorted range. Note that this is not a stable > sort: the relative order of equivalent elements is not guaranteed to be preserved.

std::sort might provide you a O(N^2) complexity in worst case based on the implementation and works on an unsorted set of data. std::sort_heap works on a heap and always gives you O(nlogn)

Comment: Actually `std::sort` is guaranteed to be `O(n*log(n))` by the standard.

Comment: @Grizzly: it is in C++11, but in C++03 it was only guaranteed "approximately n log n comparisons on average".